# Vuex + VueJS: Passing computed property to child is undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm reading through this [documentation on Vue components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events), but using Vuex data for my component properties.

From the example, if `country_id` is in the `data` method it works fine. But when `country_id` is a computed property returning data from the Vuex store, the child component's `internalValue` is always initialized as `undefined`.

What am I doing wrong?

Parent Component:

```
export default {
    computed: {
        country_id() {
            return this.$store.state.user.country_id
        }
    },
    mounted: function () {
        this.$store.dispatch('user/load');
    }
}
```

```html
<template>
   <child v-model="country_id"></child>
</template>
```

Child Component:

```
export default {
    props: [ 'value' ],
    data: function() {
        return {
            internalValue: null,
        };
    },
    mounted: function() {
        this.internalValue = this.value;
    },
    watch: {
        'internalValue': function() {
            this.$emit('input', this.internalValue);
        }
    }
};
```

```html
<template>
   <p>Value:{{value}}</p>
   <p>InternalValue:{{internalValue}}</p>
</template>
```

Answer (score 8):

Your parent component passes the value it has for `country_id` to its child component before the `mounted` lifecycle hook fires. Since your `$store.dispatch` doesn't happen until then, it is initially `undefined`.

Your child component sets its `internalValue` in its `mounted` lifecycle hook with the initial `value` prop of `undefined`. Then, when `country_id` updates in the parent, your child component's `value` property will update, but the `internalValue` will remain `undefined`.

You should make `internalValue` a computed property as well:

```
computed: {
  internalValue() {
    return this.value;
  }
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could wait to render the child component until `country_id` is defined:

```
<child v-if="country_id !== undefined" v-model="country_id"></child>
```